# How is Hypermedia to be consumed by the client in a REST architecture?

Tags: rest, restful-architecture

In learning about REST architecture, I've noticed that Hypermedia seems to be an important part of the uniform interface constraint to become RESTful; however, I'm having a hard time understanding how this concept of hypermedia is to be consumed by a client based off of the definition of hypermedia found across the web.

From what I understand about REST, hypermedia is/are basically the links that are provided to a client in a rest response containing the representation of a resource (so that the client only has to know about the base entry point url to a REST service). The links are essentially there to help the client know what options it has regarding the representation it received (for example, if I request the /children/ resource, I might receive an xml list of children that also contains links to /children/youngest, /children/oldest/, children/create, etc... This is exactly what i have a hard time understanding... Why does the server have to return these "hypermedia" links to the client? Shouldn't the client have already known about those links? The client isn't going to read the links on its own and follow them correctly... Somebody has to write client code (html and/or javascript for example) beforehand. What good do these links do for the client if the client should have already known about them? What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hypermedia is indeed an important part of creating RESTful interfaces.  However, I see a full hypermedia client ([sometimes referred to as HATEOAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS)) as just a point on the spectrum of becoming more RESTful.  The [Richardson Maturity Model](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html) describes 3 steps to becoming more RESTful and I've found these as good guidelines when considering how much of a RESTful patten to adopt on particular projects.

IMO, the best example of a full hypermedia client is a web browser.  The web browser understands that the html `<a href>` tag represents a link.  The key to a link is that a user can *discover* functionality as they move through their journey.  So, when designing a RESTful API, the same principle can be applied.

> Why does the server have to return these "hypermedia" links to the
>   client?

So, one reason is that clients (if written to expose links) can allow state transitions to be discoverable.

Another benefit to using links is your API becomes responsible for the structure and data of each link.  So, the server-side API is generating the links for each request.  This means that the server API can make changes (version or structure) to the links without breaking the client.

You can build a RESTful API without links (Richardson Level 2), but then what if you want to change the URL for one of your API requests?  You need to either implement a versioning strategy (through the url or headers) or you need to create a new url for the new feature.  Through time, this can get out of hand.

Comment: Davin, let's say I am a third-party company that has a simple HTTP accessible api that provides you with the current temperature for your city. You're a mobile app developer who wants to use my endpoint /temperature/Boston. Two questions with this scenario: 1) is my endpoint a "REST" endpoint or even close to it and if so 2)What links would I return to you in the representation of the temperature? Or would there not be any? If there were, how would you use them in your mobile app?

Comment: 1) if you follow RESTful principles for designing the URL and use the appropriate HTTP verbs you could call it RESTful.  2) How about a link to tomorrow's forecast, or next week's?  Or whatever other information (like barometric pressure or wind velocity).

Comment: If you have a simple service, accessed through GET, that given a specific url (say: http://myweather.com/temperature/f/boston), always gives the current temperature for Boston, then you basically have a REST service.

Comment: Any good example to understand client development with jQuery or AngularJS?

Answer (score 1):

Think about how browsing a web-page works. REST is very similar (although you're actually describing a related topic HATEOAS). The intent is that your client will retrieve the initial data, then have some way of deciding whether or not to request the referenced data. In a browser, some references (such as css, javascript, images) are immediately requested, and others, such as hrefs, are simply displayed to the user, and only retrieved if the user chooses to click the link. The same is true of your REST client -- you will decide for yourself, based on your requirements, which references to automatically request, and which to display to a user for decision making.

If you have an app that shows a person, along with their address, then your app would be written to automatically find the address reference in the person data and retrieve it. If your app shows a person and an option to show related data, then you'd show the person along with hyperlinks (or something similar) that allows the user to choose to retrieve and display the address data.

The issue really comes when you think about how the client visually represents the information it is retrieving. For this, the REST style suggests that you should allow the server to return javascript to dynamically parse the new data (for example, the address in my example above). Maybe the returned data also contains css-like references that will help. Maybe it'll contain javascript links to allow dynamic user interaction (which sounds dangerous to me, but what the hell, it works for the web).

Comment: I can see how this whole link (hypermedia) thing makes sense if you are returning entire html pages to the client -- it makes sense that you could use the provided links to guide the user from page to page and to perform additional functionality on representations. But what if you're just returning xml/json with specific information like weather for your client to display on the top right corner of their page? Do i need to consider hypermedia in this case?

Comment: Maybe. On my android phone I can see the weather displayed, but if I click it I get more information, and if I click that I get sent to the weather provider's page for full details. If you wanted that behavior then you should return not only the current weather details, but also a link to a more detailed weather report, and within that a link to your homepage with the location parameters in the url.

Answer (score 1):

Fielding defined the uniform interface constraint in order to decouple the clients from the implementation of the service. This is just the same as defining a new interface in any oo language. You define it to decouple a class from the implementation of its dependency.

To decouple the client from the URI structure you need links in the response, which contain semantic annotation and the URI. So your client can decide which link to follow based on the semantic annotation (e.g. [link relation](http://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml) or [a term in a related RDF vocab](http://schema.org/Action)). This way it does not need to know anything about the URI structure.

You need to decouple clients from the implementation details of the services to make them reusable. At the end you can create general clients like a web browsers today. The difference that these clients will understand what they do, so they won't necessary rely on humans.

Answer (score 0):

> What good do these links do for the client if the client should have already known about them?

They make state transitions more directly a part of the interface. They tell the client whether these links or state transitions are available to be used (or not if they are not present!) in the current state.

If the client did not take notice of this, it could potentially still try to generate and follow an URL for an option (state transition) that was actually not available. It might be necessary to replicate the logic to determine what is possible in a particular state on both sides to be sure to avoid this.

If an invalid link/state transition is attempted, the server should report back an error.

On the other hand, if the client never allowed generating/following a link not provided by the server, it could have awareness and provide feedback about the problem earlier (normally resulting in a clearer situation or error message), and while the server should handle the invalid request correctly, in case it didn't it would be less of a problem as it is much less likely to happen in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

```
        var discountDetails = new AddDiscountForm()
        {
            promotionId = 123456,
            discountType = "Promotion",
            discount = UnitValue.FromFloat(14.00)
        };

        await journey
            .SelectRoot()
            .SelectRelation("product-finder", new { barcode = "23409-23097" })
            .SelectItem(0)
            .SelectRelation("add-discount", discountDetails)
            .RunAsync();
```

In fact I took the idea from my response and built it.

https://github.com/lukepuplett/surfdude-csharp